# more than 10 program icons

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

On the Gnome shell by pressing <kbd>super</kbd>, on each icon some numbers appear from 0 to 9 based of the all number of icons which are located in there. So if have more that 10 icon what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only applies for the first nine (not ten) icons. This is because those are the numerical keys available on the keyboard. You can only use <kbd>Super</kbd> + 1 to 9 on the first nine apps.

You can try reorganizing your apps and place the one's you use mostly on top nine and the others after them. I pretty much use like six apps at most - browser, text editor, terminal, media player, gimp (occasionally) and sometimes BibleTime.

You can also unlock those apps you rarely use or which doesn't require 'launching' as per say. Take a look at the pdf reader, evince, you don't really need that on the launcher. Just select your PDF and double click it. Something like the image viewer, you don't really need that on the launcher either. Just my thoughts though.

Answer (score 0):

Place your mouse pointer at the lower end of the bar and the icons will scroll up allowing you to choose the one you desire. You can also unlock rarely used icons from the launcher.